# Single table column refers to multiple primary key

Tags: database, database-design

I need to store multiple values in a single column.

For example I am creating table which holds the user preferences

e.g.

```
| user_id | cities     | countries  |
|---------|------------|------------|
| 1       | 10, 11, 23 | 21, 34     |
```

because i can't store them as array (or don't prefer to store as array even if it is available - due to maintenance and performance reasons - and better RDMS design), i have to create a mapping table like this

```
| user_id | type    | reference_id |
|---------|---------|--------------|
| 1       | CITY    | 10           |
| 1       | CITY    | 11           |
| 1       | CITY    | 23           |
| 1       | COUNTRY | 21           |
| 1       | COUNTRY | 34           |
```

The reference id in this column refers to the master tables like city, country, etc.

The problem here i see is

- I can't have FK reference to city or country table, because single reference_id column may refer to city or country depends on the type
- As i can't have FK, there is no guaranty that we can't have dirty data

Is there any better approach?

Note:

- I have given city/country as sample, but i need to have around 20 columns which can have multiple values like city or country
- In future i may introduce some boolean preference like "whether you like to travel" so i might want to store TYPE as "TRAVEL" and referece_id as 0 for yes 1 for no; which definately will not have any reference

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Location Table {LocationId, locationType (city/country)}
and then everytime you add a new record to the city or country table, add it to location table first, then add it to city (or country) table as appropriate with same cityId (or countryId) as was used as LocationId in Location Table.

then create FK between preferences table and location table, and add [zero or one] to one `(0/1 - 1)` FK relationship between City and country tables to the Location table. (Every record in City and COuntry table tables must be in Location table, but not the other way around.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want a table for generic data instead of 20 lookup tables enforcing RI?  On a large system, the data would be stored in multiple tables instead of using a delimiter to separate the values and then exploding them out in another table, introducing the problem of enforcing RI.  If you're storing values that are really generic, like code/description pairs, you just need a codeSetID field to identify which codes belong in which codesets.